# How to copy an Object in dart without referencing it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to do something very simple. I need to build a new variable of type AlimentarModel and then modify one of its elements without modifying the original variable. I tried to do it with the = sign, but it stays linked to the original. What is the function I should use?

```
   AlimentarModel original = new AlimentarModel();
   original.consumo = 3;
   original.etiqueta = 'Good';

   AlimentarModel newVariable = original;
   newVariable.consumo = 4;

   print(original.consumo); //It prints 4. I would expect to print 3.
```

What do I need to change in order to have newVariable based on original, but independent?

Comment: see https://developer.school/dart-flutter-what-does-copywith-do so in your case it should be: `AlimentarModel copyWith({String etiqueta, int consumo}) => AlimentarModel(etiqueta: etiqueta ?? this.etiqueta, consumo: consumo ?? this.consumo);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are only copying the reference

In order to copy the object you may have to do this

```
class AlimentarModel {
  int? consumo;
  String? etiqueta;

  AlimentarModel();

  AlimentarModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    consumo = json['consumo'];
    etiqueta = json['etiqueta'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['consumo'] = this.consumo;
    data['etiqueta'] = this.etiqueta;
    return data;
  }
}

 AlimentarModel x = AlimentarModel();
  x.consumo = 3;
  x.etiqueta = "good";
  
  AlimentarModel y = AlimentarModel.fromJson(x.toJson()); //copies the object values
  y.consumo = 4;
  print(x.consumo); //prints 3
```

Comment: you should use commonly used `copyWith` method that: "allows us to copy a T and pass in arguments that overwrite settable values.", see https://developer.school/dart-flutter-what-does-copywith-do

Comment: Yes that's great too, basically both are same, both creates a new instance

Comment: it is much more easier in use: you just call one single method, thats all, for example: `AlimentarModel y = x.copyWith(consumo: 4);`

Comment: If you know any better answer, just post it. @pskink

Comment: so why dont you want to edit your answer and provide the code with the de-facto dart/flutter standard `copyWith` method? check https://api.flutter.dev/index.html for example, type `copyWith` in upper-right search box and you will see that more than 80 classes in flutters SDK code have that method

Comment: btw I posted your suggestion too. happy?

Answer (score 2):

Another Solution!

```
class AlimentarModel {
  int? consumo;
  String? etiqueta;

  AlimentarModel({this.consumo,this.etiqueta});

  AlimentarModel copyWith({int? consumo, String? etiqueta}) {
    return AlimentarModel(
      consumo: consumo ?? this.consumo,
      etiqueta: etiqueta ?? this.etiqueta
    );
  }
}

AlimentarModel original = new AlimentarModel();
   original.consumo = 3;
   original.etiqueta = 'Good';

   AlimentarModel newVariable = original.copyWith(consumo: 4);

   print(original.consumo); // prints 3
```